# primeng p-table, p-multiselect filter not showing

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

[image: p-multiselect component in p-table]

Hello everyone! i am using p-table, p-multiselect filter for a column. The problem is that p-multiselect filter is showing behind the t-body of the table please help.

Comment: You need to manage the z-index of the table and dropdown list dynamically with CSS. Please share stackblitz to get more help.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `appendTo="body"` to `p-multiSelect`, worked for me :-)